# python Determine if device supports intel vPro or not

Tags: python, winapi, intel

I want to make a simple code to determine if a device supports intel vPro or not,
I've tried some of the suggestions on https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74767bb3-d840-443f-a4ac-0b02b6077fb8/determine-if-device-supports-vpro?forum=configmanagerosd but I still couldn't determine a device that support vPro or not.

can any one suggest me, how simple way to determine it ?

Thanks